# Return type mismatch when throwing exception in finally

Tags: kotlin

I am using Kotlin 1.2.60.

```
val someString: String = try {

    String.format("Okay %s", "there") // or any function that returns String

} catch(exception: Exception) {

    try {
        // fun incrementErrorCount() { ... }
        incrementErrorCount() // [1] Error: Type mismatch: Inferred type is Unit but String was expected
    } finally {
        throw exception
    }

    // throw exception // [2] Fixes the type mismatch when uncommented, but raises Warning: Unreachable code
}
```

I get a *Type mismatch* error at `1` because it expects `incrementErrorCount()` to return a String — but the return type shouldn't matter, because it is always going to re-throw `exception` anyway.

I added `2`, which fixes the *Type mismatch* error, but raises an *Unreachable code* warning because the function never proceeds beyond the `throw` in `finally`.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get this to compile without errors or warnings?

Comment: If you are any how throwing the exception, Why use `finally` block? Write the throw exception directly after `try`  block which would make that the last statement of your `catch` block.

Answer (score 2):

See the [Kotlin Reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html#try-is-an-expression) for `try-catch-finally` and you'll see:

> The returned value of a `try`-expression is either the last expression in the `try` block or the last expression in the `catch` block (or blocks). **Contents of the `finally` block do not affect the result of the expression.**

So this means that while your intention is correct, and there is no way to return from your second `try` block, the Kotlin compiler will still take `Unit` as it's return value and not modify it due to the specification of the `finally` block.

To make the compiler aware of the fact that the `catch` block will always return `Nothing`, you need to **move the `throw` out of the `finally` block**.

Comment: That reference link certainly describes the _Type mismatch_ error on `1`. I'm surprised that despite that, it still gives me an _Unreachable code_ warning if I have the throw at `2`. It also gives me the same warning if I add a `throw ce` after `incrementErrorCount()` instead. Like it recognizes that the `finally { throw }` block means there's no return value, but doesn't apply logic that to the call's return value.

Comment: @mrb Yes, the `finally` block is always executed, and since it always throws, the code below is unreachable. But still, the return type that's inserted by the compiler is `Unit` instead of `Nothing`, which gives you the error

Answer (score 0):

`try-catch` is an expression in Kotlin. If the `try` block runs successfully without throwing anything, its last value is returned. If it throws an exception, the `catch` block's last value is returned.

In your case, if `String.format` doesn't throw an exception, its result is returned from the first `try-catch`, and you're good. This is the easy route.

If `String.format` throws an exception, the last expression of the `catch` block is returned, which is the second, nested `try-finally` itself. This can end two ways:

- If the nested `try` block runs successfully, its last expression (in this case, `incrementErrorCount`) is what it evaluates to, and then the result of that call would be assigned to `someString`. This is the type error you're getting, it looks like `incrementErrorCount` doesn't return a `String` to assign.
- If the nested `try` fails, you throw an exception, cancelling the assignment of `someString` altogether.

Adding line [2] fixes your error because the nested `try-catch` isn't used as the value to assign to `someString`, it's just ran and the `throw` expression cancels the entire assignment of `someString`.

Comment: Wrong. `finally` is always executed, no matter if the `try` block threw an exception or not

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your desired logic is that if String.format fails, you let the exception be thrown, but also increment your error count. In that case, I think you need (untested)...

```
val someString: String = try {

    String.format("Okay %s", "there") // or any function that returns String

} catch(exception: Exception) {

    try {
        // fun incrementErrorCount() { ... }
        incrementErrorCount()
    } 
    catch (dontCare: Exception) {
    }

    throw exception 

}
```

Comment: the question is _What am I doing wrong?_, and you don't give any explanation why the code in the question is not working

Comment: I think you're mixing up your catch blocks. If I understand your intention correctly, the inner block is just there to swallow exceptions from incrementErrorCount(). So just make it do that. The outer block can re-throw the exception that belongs to it.

Comment: I would interpret the code in the question the same way (still one would probably want to log errors that occured in `incrementErrorCount()` but that's another topic). Still you don't explain why the code of the question fails to compile

Comment: "Contents of the finally block do not affect the result of the expression." https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html